# How to specify node_modules directory for Typescript explicitly

Tags: typescript

I have following problem. I have two apps directories app1 and app2. I would like to reuse some of the code from app1 in app2. To achieve this I introduce type alias in tsconfig.json:
`"~/*":["../../app1/src/*"]`
This works ok when import files which don't have any imports. But if there is an import I get errors like this: Cannot find module 'react' or its corresponding type declarations.
If I install node_modules for app1 it works ok too, but I would like Typescript to use node_modules folder of the project app2 for files imported from app1. Is this possible to achieve?

package.json for app2:

```json
{
  "name": "app2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.8",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "ts-loader": "^8.0.7",
    "typescript": "^4.0.5",
    "webpack": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-cli": "^4.1.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json for app2:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./src",
      "jsx": "react",
      "paths": {
        "~/*": ["../../app1/src/*"]
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the shared code in a "standalone" library that will be depended on by both apps.

This library could have its own dependancies and peer dependencies (`react` is a good candidate for a peer dependency).

Otherwise, you **have** to add the dependency required by the code you import in each app importing it. This is because you are importing it like a "standalone" source file, totally indepedant from app1.

Comment: Yes that would be ideal solution but unfortunately I am not able to afford doing this at the moment as this will result in major refactoring of a fairly large project.

Comment: I am not following your last paragraph of your answer. That is what exactly I am trying to do, import source file from app1 but node_modules from app2. Obviously I installed all the dependencies in the app2 but Typescript only looks in node_modules of the app1 project.

Comment: Did you install all the dependencies needed for the file in app2 ? You also need to install the dev dependencies (typings). Here, you would need `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom`.

Comment: Yes I did, all dependencies are installed in app2. If I install also in the app1 then it works but due to setup I would like to have node_modules only in app2 folder.

Comment: could you share `package.json` for app1 and app2 ?

Comment: I added to the post description package.json and tsconfig.json for app2. app1 does not have any at the moment. I just want to use it as a source directory.

Comment: You need to add react typings declaration to app2. See my previous comment about dev dependencies.

Comment: Good point, not sure why I missed that. I have updated package.json but it did not help, still same issue.

Comment: Did you run `npm install` after making the changes? Also, you should put the typings in the `devDependencies` section: https://docs.npmjs.com/specifying-dependencies-and-devdependencies-in-a-package-json-file

Comment: Yes I did(I did not manually edited package.json). I know about devDependencies but that should not affect module resolution at all. This is just small test project where I am trying to make things work.